# Cloning a JavaScript function: anything else better than using eval?

Tags: javascript, oop

**EDITED**

*Note: I've completely edited this because previous problem was solved using another approach and I've simplified this question in order to answer myself with my solution to the question and share my conclusion with you.*

How to clone a function by avoiding the use of `eval(...)`?

I need to get an exact copy of some given function and this must be a different object than source one.

That's `functionA != functionCloneOfA`, and wrapping "functionA" and calling it from the body of some other isn't a solution for me.

Comment: What's the difference between a object constructor and a javascript-function??? Anyways, can't you just do this: `var funcB = funcA`? Functions are first-class citizens in javascript meaning that what object they are stuck on doesn't matter at all. All that matters is how you call them.

Comment: Check one of my points to solve the problem: **If same function instance is stored in some variable or field so actual and overridden functions can be accessed from different points will end in both references will point to the same object, so this isn't a solution.**.

Comment: @Alxandr ah, and there's no difference, but I wanted to note that I'm not talking about an object constructor, but an actual function. Like a "helloWorld" one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unable to understand that sentence, so I don't know what the problem is. But I do know that javascript-functions do not keep a reference to the object upon which they are stored (unless they use that object explicitly and not with the `this` keyword).

Comment: Sec, I'm going to explain that better in question's body, please hold.

Comment: How about this: `theObject.prototype.$base$.funcName = function(){theFunk.call(this, arguments)}`? That way you'd made a new function that does nothing but run the old one in the current contex. Though I can't really see the difference between this and actually copying the function except the extra call-stack-step you get.

Comment: No, this isn't a solution too, because what happens if "theFunk" is of another prototype? "theFunk" call will be of B prototype, instead of A. Think that this is simulating inheritance "B inherits A", so functions of A must be of B, and **this** must we always "B".

Comment: What would happen if you declared some private field in B constructor. How "theFunk" body will access them if "theFunk" is of A.prototype?

Comment: Javascript has no private fields.

Comment: It has them. Variables declared in an object constructor (ok, it's a regular function) like "this._blah" will be available in the context of prototype's functions.

Comment: Also, even if you do this: `function B() { this.theVar = 'test'; }; B.prototype.getVar = function() {return this.theVar;}` there is no problem with running the getVar function on a Date-object like this: `B.prototype.getVar.call(new Date(), [])`, you'd only get undefined in return. Also, if you defined the getVar-function as this: `return this.getFullYear();` it'd return the fullyear when called on the Date-object, but undefined when called on a B-object.

Comment: Haha, and we arrived to the problem! I need B is A, so B has A functions, and this means B functions must have access to A constructor variables.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but they will be accessible from all over. Take this example: `function B() { this.theVar = 'test' }; var b = new B(); alert(b.theVar);`. As you can clearly see, NOT private. Also, you can do this: `function getVar() { return this.theVar; }; getVar.call(b, []);`.

Comment: @Alxandr it's a metaphor or a near-to-private field approach. I know you've public access to them, but if you follow good OOP practices, they act as private fields.

Comment: Anyways, I'd suggest you to focus in the way of how to completely clone a function and make this clone a different instance of source function.

Comment: If you have to use class-based OOP in JavaScript, I'd suggest to use an implementation of a standard lib, like Prototype, that allows inheritance and the use of `super`. If you really need to roll your own, I'd suggest to have a look at this article: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ that shows a nice implementation of `super`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The fact is I've developed my own OOP-only JavaScript library and I was looking to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I didn't need to clone functions to solve some problem in one of my projects, but I want to share with you what I found in order to truly clone a function:

```
function cloneFunc(someFunc) {
    var someFuncAsText = someFunc.toString();

    return new Function
    (
        /\(([\s\S]*?)\)/.exec(someFunc)[1],
        someFuncAsText.substring(someFuncAsText.indexOf("{") + 1, someFuncAsText.lastIndexOf("}"))
    );
}
```

I'm not absolutely sure this is the best approach around, but it produces an anonymous function which is an **exact** clone of source function, but both are different objects.

Perhaps uses some kind of "eval" because I'm building a function by using this Function object constructor, but I believe it's more elegant than an actual use of **eval(...)**.

Comment: An issue with this approach is that it only works with native functions, it won't work with built–in or host functions. So you should check that the return value of `someFunc.toString()` doesn't have a body like `{[native code]}`. Also, calling the Function constructor is often seen as equivalent to calling *eval* (without wishing to cast aspersions on *eval*, it's just a comment, but some feel strongly about its use).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Lasse Reichstein Nielsen's "clone" function? Essentially it "clones" a function by returning a new object that has the function on it's prototype chain. Douglas Crockford calls his version ["beget"](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html).

```
var cloneFn = (function() {
    var F = function(){};
    return function(fn) {
        F.prototype = fn;
        return new F();
    }
}());

var myClone = cloneFn(someFn);
```

Returns an object whose [[prototype]] is the "cloned" `someFn` function.

Comment: But how can I call "myClone"?

Comment: Check my own answer, I'll go this way. Thank you for your effort anyway.

Comment: This is brilliant. I had to make one small change to have it behave as I expected by returning `return new F().prototype.constructor`. Excellent job citing sources. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you need now. What you need is simply to call the A's constructor on the B-object, like this:

```
function A() { this._someVal = 'test'; }
function B() { this._someOtherVal = 'test2'; }
B.prototype = new A(); // this is how inheritance is normally done in Javascript.
B.prototype.getVal = function() { return this._someVal; }

var b = new B();
alert(b.getVal());
alert(b._someVal);
alert(b._someOtherVal);
```

If you don't want to do it that way, you can call the A-constructor from inside B like this:

```
function B() { A.call(this, []); this._someOtherVal = 'test2'; }
```

but than you need to manually copy all the prototype-functions from A to B.

Comment: +1 I've upvoted it because in another situation it'd be the right answer, but it's a good answer anyway. Thanks for your effort. I'm trying to get @RobG solution work.